# Bernoulli Equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

[image]

I have this equation I am trying to solve, I'm not sure if I did it correctly, but here's my work:

$$y' +y(x^2-1) + xy^6 =0$$
$$y' + y(x^2-1) = -xy^6 $$
$$v = y^{-5}, v' = -5y^{-6}y'$$
$$y' = \frac{-y^{6}v'}{5}$$

Substituting in:
$$\frac{-y^{6}v'}{5} + y(x^2-1) =-xy^6$$
$$v' -5v(x^2-1) = 5x$$

So this is now the linear form, therefore $$r(x) = e^{-5\int x^2-1} = e^{-5(\frac{x^3}{3}-x)}$$

At this point, I multiplied each side by r(x):

$$e^{-5(\frac{x^3}{3}-x)}v' -5v(x^2-1)e^{-5(\frac{x^3}{3}-x)} = e^{-5(\frac{x^3}{3}-x)}5x$$

And then I rewrote it like this:

$$\frac{d}{dx} \bigg [e^{-5(\frac{x^3}{3}-x)}v)\bigg ] = e^{-5(\frac{x^3}{3}-x)}5x$$

From here it's obvious to integrate both sides, doing so yields:

$$e^{-5(\frac{x^3}{3}-x)}v(x) = 5\int xe^{-5(\frac{x^3}{3}-x)} dx$$

I don't know what to do from here

Thanks

Comment: Hint: answers need not always be in closed form

Comment: @YuBut what do I do with the initial condition?

Answer (score 1):

Starting from your second-to-last line
$$ \frac{d}{dx}\left[\exp\left(-\frac{5x^3}{3}+5x\right)v(x) \right] = 5x \exp\left(-\frac{5x^3}{3}+5x\right) $$

A convenient way to proceed is to integrate from the given initial point
$$ \exp\left(-\frac{5x^3}{3}+5x\right)v(x) = \int_1^x 5t \exp\left(-\frac{5t^3}{3}+5t\right)dt + C $$

Plugging in $x=1$ gives $C = e^{10/3}$, so
$$ v(x) = \exp\left(\frac{5x^3}{3}-5x\right)\left[\int_1^x 5t \exp\left(-\frac{5t^3}{3}+5t\right)dt + e^{10/3}\right] $$

Then just take $y = v^{-1/5}$ and you're done

Answer (score 0):

I assume your solution up to this point is correct, so we are dealing with:

$$e^{-5(\frac{x^3}{3}-x)}v(x) = 5\int xe^{-5(\frac{x^3}{3}-x)} dx$$

You ask: "what do I do with the initial condition?"

It's $y(1)=1$, which means that $v(1)=y(1)^{-5}=1$.

When you have a solution in the form of an integral, the initial condition determines its limits:

$$e^{-5(\frac{1}{3}-1)}v(1) = 5\int_{x_0}^1 xe^{-5(\frac{x^3}{3}-x)} dx$$

Rewriting:

$$\int_{x_0}^1 xe^{-5(\frac{x^3}{3}-x)} dx=\frac{1}{5} e^{10/3}$$

This equation determines $x_0$. Which means, your solution should be:

$$v(x) = 5 e^{5(\frac{x^3}{3}-x)}\int_{x_0}^x xe^{-5(\frac{x^3}{3}-x)} dx$$

Where $x_0$ is now known.

Comment: But don't you need to resub v(x) for it in terms of y?

Comment: Why? We just rewrite the initial condition in terms of $v$, as you can see

Comment: I thought we were supposed to solve for y.

Comment: So? You have $v=y^{-5}$, which means $y=v^{-1/5}$

Comment: Yes, so don't you plug in v(x) = y^-5 and then take the fifth root of both sides?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Please point out the step of my solution you seem to be confused about and how you think it should be done instead.